# Background color in uialertaction cancel button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I have a `MenuActionSheet`. I need to to change the font size, style of the options and also want to change the background color of the 'Cancel' button.

According to the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: MenuActionSheet is a custom class. Can you be more specific about the base class?

Comment: It's UIActionSheet

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53424527/1919303

Answer (score 0):

This level of customisation can only be achieved by overwriting the drawing methods of your action sheet (it inherits from UIView).

*Note: UIActionSheet is deprecated since iOS 8. For more information see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/*