# UIAlertController change background color of Cancel button for action sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I am trying to create a UIAlertController with the action sheet style but I want to change the background color to a gray color. I have been able to find a way to change the background color of the UIAlertController, but not the Cancel button. The Cancel button, which is separate, remains white.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 3" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:nil]];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];

UIView *firstSubview = alert.view.subviews.firstObject;
UIView *alertContentView = firstSubview.subviews.firstObject;

for (UIView *subSubView in alertContentView.subviews) {
    subSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; // Here you change background
}

alert.view.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.controller presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this gives me the following result:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpk9D.png)

I have visited [How to change the background color of the UIAlertController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863460/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-uialertcontroller)
 but none of the solutions have a custom color for the background of the Cancel button.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to change the back ground color for cancel button?

Comment: See my coding I changed the cancel button color to darkGray color.

Comment: I want the Cancel button to have dark gray background color and white text. Your code doesn't seem to do that but does the opposite: your background color of your Cancel button is white, and your text color is gray

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change color of a default cancel button style. You need to create a custom view controller for the cancel button and set it as a content view controller of a cancel alert action. This way keeps the cancel button separately

[image]

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option 1", style: .default, handler: nil))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option 2", style: .default, handler: nil))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option 3", style: .default, handler: nil))

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: nil))

if let firstSubview = alertController.view.subviews.first, let alertContentView = firstSubview.subviews.first {
    for view in alertContentView.subviews {
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    }
}

alertController.view.tintColor = .white

let cancelButtonViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CancelButtonViewController")
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
cancelAction.setValue(cancelButtonViewController, forKey: "contentViewController")

alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: controller constraints are broken. Cancel button overlaps last item if you have more than 10 items

Comment: @geek1706 cancel button overlaps the last item

Answer (score 11):

There is a very very dirty solution but it works. We are going to use **UIAppearance** for this purpose.

First of all we need to prepare a special private extension for UIView to be able to change it's subviews background color.

```
fileprivate extension UIView {
    private struct AssociatedKey {
        static var subviewsBackgroundColor = "subviewsBackgroundColor"
    }

    @objc dynamic var subviewsBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get { 
          return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.subviewsBackgroundColor) as? UIColor 
        }

        set {
          objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                                   &AssociatedKey.subviewsBackgroundColor,
                                   newValue,
                                   .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
          subviews.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = newValue }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time we set **subiewsBackgroundColor** value UIView will iterate it's subviews and set a new background color for each.

As you can see in the answer below there is a special UIView called **_UIAlertControlleriOSActionSheetCancelBackgroundView** in UIAlertController's hierarchy which contains a subview with white color (for the cancel button)

Let's try to get it's appearance and use our property to change it's subview color. I guess it's kind of a private api.

```
if let cancelBackgroundViewType = NSClassFromString("_UIAlertControlleriOSActionSheetCancelBackgroundView") as? UIView.Type {
    cancelBackgroundViewType.appearance().subviewsBackgroundColor = .red
}
```

Place this code in the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching or a dedicated class.
That's it. Now you can see the cancel button on a red background. Tested on iOS 11.

Comment: how to get to _UIVisualEffectSubview?

Comment: Class prefixed with `_` is private class of iOS and tweaking nonpublic classes might lead to App rejection or nonpublic internal class can be changed in any update breaks your application'sUI.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a separate Cancel Button(UIAlertActionStyleCancel) you can't change the background color of the cancel button. If it's your priority then you have to make your own custom View. Or else you can simply add a default action with the title "Cancel".

`[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]]`

(But it won't give you a separate button).

I have debugged the view hierarchy and found this. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I used the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49066544) by [mbryzinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3328810/mbryzinski) in my mixed Objective-C / Swift project and was able to modify the Cancel button background color from Objective-C like this:

```
((UIView *)[NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertControlleriOSActionSheetCancelBackgroundView")
 appearance]).subviewsBackgroundColor = [UIColor yourBackgroundColor];
```

I included the UIView extension as a .swift file in the project and I had to **remove** the **fileprivate** keyword:

```
extension UIView {
    private struct AssociatedKey {
        static var subviewsBackgroundColor = "subviewsBackgroundColor"
    }
    @objc dynamic var subviewsBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
    ...
```

Also, the bridging header needs to be imported in the file where the extension is used:

```
#import "{Your Project's name}-Swift.h"
```

Modifying the background and text colors of an UIAlertController is a quick (and honestly dirty) way for implementing a dark theme.
There are some slight artifacts around the rounded corners, that become more visible, the darker the background color gets. Especially on the iPad, the artifacts are quite visible.

The correct solution would probably be to use a custom Alert Controller. (Haven't found one yet that looks mostly like the stock one.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution now. I created sample project and worked out for your question and I got it.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Option 3" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:nil]];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];

    UIView *subView = alert.view.subviews.lastObject; //firstObject
    UIView *alertContentView = subView.subviews.lastObject; //firstObject
    [alertContentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    alert.view.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

See the output

[image]

Comment: I don't think you understood my question properly. The background color of your Cancel button is still white, and your text is now gray. I need the opposite to happen